# NameError: global name 'QContextMenuEvent' is not defined

Tags: python, menu, pyqt5

I want to add a right click menu.

```
def contextMenuEvent(self,event):
    global posX
    global posY
    global selections,scan_widget

    if event.reason() == QContextMenuEvent.Mouse:
        menu = QMenu(self)
        clear = menu.addAction('Clear')

        for i in selections:
            self.buttonLabels.append(menu.addAction(i))

        deleteBox = menu.addAction('Delete Box')
        changeId = menu.addAction('Change Id')
        cancel = menu.addAction('Cancel')
        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        for i,key in enumerate(self.buttonLabels):
            if action == key:
                self.annotClass = selections[i]
                self.annotEnabled = True
        if action == deleteBox:
            self.deleteEnabled = True
        elif action == changeId:
            #Call the textbox
            self.newBoxId = textBox()
            self.newBoxId.setGeometry(QRect(500, 100, 300, 100))
            self.newBoxId.show()
        elif action == cancel:
            pass
        elif action == clear:
            self.annotClass = 'Clear'
            self.annotEnabled = True

        self.posX_annot = event.pos().x()
        self.posY_annot = event.pos().y()

        posX = event.pos().x()
        posY = event.pos().y()

        self.repaint()
        self.buttonLabels = []
    self.annotEnabled = False
```

But give me back this error:

> NameError: global name 'QContextMenuEvent' is not defined

Then, I added QContextMenuEvent as import:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton,QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QWidget,QLineEdit, QInputDialog, QMenu,QContextMenuEvent)
```

But,

> ImportError: cannot import name QContextMenuEvent

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you do a 'pip freeze' in the terminal? looks like you are missing a package

Comment: The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python-pip

Comment: How did you install PyQt5? that's the python module needed for that library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

`if event.reason() == QContextMenuEvent.Mouse:`

with

`if event.button == Qt.RightButton:`

Answer (score 2):

From what I googled, `QContextMenuEvent` class resides in the `QtGui` module which can be imported from `PyQt5`

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QContextMenuEvent
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named QtGui

Comment: I installed `PyQt5` and checked. The module `PyQt5` does have the `QtGui` module. Please check again.